# Finding Correlations in Categorical Survey Results using the Chi Squared Test in R

Tags: r, correlation, chi-squared-test

I recently conducted a survey for Dungeons & Dragons Dungeon Masters to better learn how DMs prepare and run their games. I have all of the counts per answer graphed out using ggplot2 which is all well and good but I want to dig deeper into the data with R and am looking for some help with identifying correlations between questions. I don't have a background in statistics but I've read up on chi squared tests and attempted to conduct them in R but with little success.

I've also been interested in displaying correlations between questions using the corrplot library but all of the examples seem to focus on a single set of variables and their relationship to each other. I don't know how that works when you have multiple questions with multiple categorical answers.

I was hoping you folks might walk me through how I can better analyze the results of this survey and find correlations between the data.

Here is a copy of the current survey data in csv.

http://s3.amazonaws.com/slyflourish_content/dm_survey_clean.csv

Here's the first five rows in CSV:

```
Timestamp,Frequency of Games,Length of Games,Primary Locations,Campaign Worlds,Adventures,Preferred Combat Type,Preparation Time,Campaign and Worldbuilding,Story and Adventures,Combat Encounters,NPC Development,Exploration and Roleplay,Treasure and Magic Items,Prop and Handouts
2016/10/28 6:40:17 PM AST,Monthly,About six hours,Home,Personal setting,No answer,5' gridded combat,About four hours,About 30 minutes,More than two hours,About 30 minutes,About 30 minutes,About 15 minutes,None,About 15 minutes
2016/10/28 6:43:20 PM AST,Weekly,About six hours,Home,Personal setting,No answer,Abstract maps,About an hour,About 15 minutes,About 15 minutes,About 30 minutes,About 15 minutes,About 15 minutes,None,About 30 minutes
2016/10/28 6:47:04 PM AST,Less than monthly,About four hours,Home,Forgotten Realms,No answer,Abstract maps,About three hours,About 30 minutes,About 30 minutes,About an hour,About 15 minutes,About 15 minutes,About 30 minutes,About an hour
2016/10/28 6:47:38 PM AST,Monthly,About four hours,Home,Forgotten Realms,No answer,Theater of the Mind,More than four hours,None,About an hour,About an hour,About 30 minutes,About an hour,About 30 minutes,About 30 minutes
2016/10/28 6:53:59 PM AST,Weekly,About four hours,Roll20,Personal setting,No answer,Abstract maps,About three hours,More than two hours,About an hour,About 30 minutes,About an hour,About an hour,About 5 minutes,About 30 minutes
```

In attemting to perform a chi squared test, I wrote the following code:

```
library(corrplot)

d <- read.csv("~/Desktop/dm_survey_clean.csv")

columns <- c("Timestamp", "Frequency of Games","Length of Games",
              "Primary Locations","Campaign Worlds","Adventures",
              "Preferred Combat Type","Preparation Time","Campaign and Worldbuilding",
              "Story and Adventures","Combat Encounters","NPC Development",
              "Exploration and Roleplay","Treasure and Magic Items","Prop and Handouts")

names(d) <- columns

i <- 2
x <- 6

t <- as.data.frame(table(c(d[columns_to_compare[i]],d[columns_to_compare[x]])))
var1 <- gsub(" ", ".", columns_to_compare[i])
var2 <- gsub(" ", ".", columns_to_compare[x])
m <- dcast(t, get(var1) ~ get(var2), value.var="Freq")
rownames(m) <- m[,1]
m <- m[ -c(1) ]
print(columns_to_compare[i])
print(columns_to_compare[x])
print(chisq.test(m, simulate.p.value = TRUE))
corrplot(cor(m))
```

Here are some specific questions:

1. How do I perform a chi squared test on these results that are meaningful? Right now I don't trust the results I'm getting.
2. How can I display an interesting correlation plot using corrplot on these data?

Comment: "dig deeper" is a bit vague. Were there particular kinds of things you were hoping to find out/particular questions you wanted to see if you could answer?

Comment: Hi Glen. I was mainly looking into how I could better perform a chi squared test on the results of multiple questions each with multiple categorical answers. Preferably with examples in R.